# What is the typical composition of English Breakfast tea?

Tags: tea

"English Breakfast" tea usually combines blends from Assam, Ceylon, and Kenya.

Typically what proportions of these three teas are used?

Edit: I have been asked to edit to explain why the answers to the question "Is English Breakfast the same as Assam?" does not answer this question. The reason is that the answers to that other question do not say what proportions of which blends typically constitute English Breakfast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does English Breakfast Tea equal Assam Tea?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25958/does-english-breakfast-tea-equal-assam-tea)

Comment: From the accepted answer to the "Is English Breakfast the same as Assam?" question: "I believe that 'English Breakfast Tea' is a very broad definition and doesn't refer to an exact blend; each manufacturer has their own version of it.". So I'm guessing there isn't actually any possible answer to your question.

Comment: We don't usually close questions just when the answers of one question fit the answer of another one, we typically also want the questions to be the same. Linking to questions with highly relevant answers is welcome!

Comment: @Elenna123 - "Typical" implies variation and implies neither "universal" or "exact".

Comment: @Elenna123 from my understanding, OP wants to make their own English Breakfast but has no idea how to balance the different components - as I mentioned in my answer, blending is a *very* specialized job regardless of product (tea, coffee, chocolate, tobacco, natural extracts) and the best a layperson can do in this front is get a recipe from somebody else and then adjust to their liking.

Comment: There is no standard or typical blend of English Breakfast tea. English breakfast was originally plain old Chinese keemun. In theory any blending attempt would try to imitate keemun, but there is no standard way to do it. And some producers don't even attempt to imitate keemun.

Answer (score 4):

There's no standard blend for English Breakfast tea, and different tea companies may have their own flavor profile they want to achieve. Generally, the goal is to create a more robust tea that goes well with milk.

Traditionally, teas from Assam, Ceylon and Kenya are used for the blend. However, today, teas from more locations are used. The benefit of blending teas from more regions is that the 'average' flavor will stay more consistent throughout the seasons and years. For the tea taster, it's therefore possible to make just small tweaks to maintain that same flavor and aroma profile.

In the tea community, you've people who like consistency and go for tea bags and blends, and you've people who like diversity and go for single-origin.

Answer (score 3):

Well, blending is *not* easy and to do it in order to have a consistent product it requires quite the accurate nose. There is a reason why blender (for whatever product) is a very specialized job requiring natural disposition and years of training.

And of course, the final product composition from both big and small companies is a very well guarded secret.

Here are some suggestions, you should try it out and see what you like.

[Assamica's Indian version of English Breakfast](https://www.assamicaagro.in/blogs/posts/making-your-own-english-breakfast-tea)

[Steepster forum (Tea lovers) discussing their own blends](https://steepster.com/discuss/6134-blending-black-teas-for-yourself)